# Section wise form for iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface

[Req UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZain.jpg)I am new to ios app development.
I need to make a user registration form where user can fill their details in 3 section- personal, professional and final registration.
I don't want to create a long form. Instead of that i want to create an UI like the attached image.
Please help me to achieve this.
Any tutorials/ blog which can help me to achieve this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a segmented controller with 3 section you will show part of the form depending of view you want and all @IBOulet will be in the same view
here is a tutorial for it 
https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/segmented-control-tutorial-ios10